# WHERE Statement in VB. NET OleDB / SQL Query

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb, oledbconnection

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question! I am new to all this and I am trying my best to work out the solution but I keep hitting a brick wall. I'm trying to update a table in a MDB file with the value of a String, where other conditions are met in another part of the table. I realise calling on strings is bad practise!

I think the problem is with the WHERE part of the SQL statement?

Appreciate any help, here is part of the code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Declerations For Calling on
    Dim AnimalHouse As String
    AnimalHouse = "TestText"
    Dim AddressForAssingment As Integer
    AddressForAssingment = 1
    Dim IDCheckAssignment As Integer
    IDCheckAssignment = 1

    'Connection Information 
    Dim myConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + ProjectDirectory.Text)
    Dim myCommand As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO IOInformation SET Description= '" & AnimalHouse & "' WHERE ID_number= '" & AddressForAssingment & "' AND ID_Check= '" & IDCheckAssignment & "'")
    myCommand.Connection = myConnection
    myConnection.Open()
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myConnection.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT` and `UPDATE` are two different commands.

Your query is a mix of both right now, what you want is possibly something like:

```
UPDATE IOInformation SET Description = .... WHERE ...
```

Comment: Thanks - It's been a massive learning curve today! I've changed it to UPDATE and I'm now getting a Data Type Mismatch... Back to searching! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Like this. Please look into [Parameterized Queries](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=parameterized%20queries&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.codinghorror.com%2Fblog%2F2005%2F04%2Fgive-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html&ei=S0HkUvHyJsq8yAHIqIDgDA&usg=AFQjCNHt4QN4NLsK12Zt-C7BXPFquF4yGw&sig2=BJ7CPzbstZIiIkNrl38oEw&bvm=bv.59930103,d.aWc).

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
 'Declerations For Calling on
 Dim AnimalHouse As String
 AnimalHouse = "TestText"
 Dim AddressForAssingment As Integer
 AddressForAssingment = 1
 Dim IDCheckAssignment As Integer
 IDCheckAssignment = 1

 'Connection Information 
 Dim myConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + ProjectDirectory.Text)
 Dim myCommand As New OleDbCommand("Update IOInformation SET [Description] = @animalHouse, WHERE ID_number = @addrForAssn AND ID_Check = @Id))
 myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@animalHouse", AnimalHouse)
 myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addrForAssn", AddressForAssingment)
 myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", IDCheckAssignment)
 myCommand.Connection = myConnection
 myConnection.Open()
 myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
 myConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll do some research into that. I'm getting a new error now! Apparently my "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list".

Comment: I've put a " before the array starts ("Update IOInformation SET [Description] = '{0}' WHERE ID_number = '{1}' AND ID_Check = '{2}'", AnimalHouse, AddressForAssingment, IDCheckAssignment)) and I've gone back to having a data type mismatch. I'm guessing I was missing a " as I got build errors otherwise?