# Why is SQL not picking up parameter

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm executing the code below but i am getting an error message saying that `one or more required parameters is not provided`. The only parameter that I can see is the `strMyDomain` which is provided. I put the MessageBox statement in temporarily just to confirm that the variable is getting a value. I must not have coded the SQL correctly to pick the value up but I can't see the error.

```
Dim strMyDomain = Environment.UserDomainName
MessageBox.Show("User domain is: " & strMyDomain)
Dim tblArchTable As New DataTable
Using myConn As New OleDbConnection(strConnectionString)
    Dim adpArchives As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ArchID, ArchUserName, ArchUserDomain,  ArchDate, ArchRoot, ArchStatus FROM Archives WHERE ArchUserDomain = strMyDomain;", myConn)
    adpArchives.Fill(tblArchTable)
    DataGV1.DataSource = tblArchTable
End Using
```

Comment: Shouldn't it have single quotes around the value of `strMyDomain` as well as concatenating the value not the name of the variable or shouldn't you be passing a parameter to the query using `OleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@domain", strMyDomain)`? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357271/where-statement-in-vb-net-oledb-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this :

```
Dim adpArchives As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ArchID, ArchUserName, ArchUserDomain, 
ArchDate, ArchRoot, ArchStatus FROM Archives WHERE ArchUserDomain = '" & strMyDomain & "'", myConn)
```

But it has sql injection risk, best practice is to use parameterized query like below :

```
Dim adpArchives As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ArchID, ArchUserName, ArchUserDomain, 
ArchDate, ArchRoot, ArchStatus FROM Archives WHERE ArchUserDomain = ?", myConn)

adpArchives.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@strMyDomain", strMyDomain))
```

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used.

For more detail, please read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx)

Comment: I tried the second example that you provided to eliminate the possibility of SQL Injection. However, I got a run-time error saying "An OleDbParameter with Parameter Name '@strMyDomain' is not contained by this OleDbParameterCollection." Not sure what I've got wrong...

Comment: @RossfromBrooklin Please let the community know if the updated answer worked or not. This way others(like you) will get benefited.